# In jQuery, should I choose live(), delegate() or on()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

I've read the jQuery documentation on event handling, but I still can't really understand what I should do.

I have a mobile app where content is loaded with ajax, so events can't be bound at document onLoad for that content.

As my application grow I now start to be concerned that wrong event handling can give performance problem.

**What is the implications on performance  choosing between on(), live() and delegate() ?**

Something else to take into consideration?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From jQuery 1.7, the official (and most performant) way to bind events is `.on` and `.off`. It's fastest when combined with an `id` based selector:

```
$('#id').on('click', myHandler);
```

`.on` supercedes `.live` `.delegate` and `.bind`, see here for more info:

http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/

Answer (score 4):

Starting with jQuery 1.7, it is recommended that all new code going forward use `on()` and `off()` for all event handling.

http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/03/jquery-1-7-released/

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7 the jQuery team/API advise that:

> [the] .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Reference: [`live()` API reference, at: http://api.jquery.com/live/](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

So the choice, post jQuery 1.7, is between `on()` and `delegate()`; and the recommendation, above, seems to suggest that you should use `.on()` in preference to `delegate()`. Although I can't argue as to *why* that is.

Comment: So you don't see any difference between on() and delegate, except that on() is recommend?

Comment: Honestly, no; except that it *feels* as if they're tidying up jQuery somewhat, and the idea of `.on()` and `.off()` seems to imply that `.delegate()`, since it seems to do much the same thing as `.on()`, will likely be deprecated in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're creating a javascript application for yourself or for your own product, you should use jQuery 1.7 and `.on()` method.

In case you're doing some kind of plugin, which can be used on older versions, I would use `.delegate()`